# jQuery Maximum characters in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to fill a div with single characters.
The div should be the width of the viewport. I get the width with:

```
$(window).width();
```

JS should build a HTML-code like this:

```
<div id="text">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
```

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Are you using a fixed width font?

Comment: You mean it `$("div").width()` for get width?

Comment: To be honest - nothing. I don't know how to begin. I only know what I want to have.

Comment: @CMedina Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a character size can be fixed or not accordig to the font I suggest to use a function to approximate the numbers of characters to print:

```js
function writeMaxNumCharsInOneLine(textObj, charToWrite) {
  var innWidth = textObj.innerWidth();
  textObj.append('<span id="charSize" style="visibility: visible; white-space: nowrap;">' + charToWrite + '</span>');
  var charSize = $('#charSize').width();
  var numCharsToWrite = (innWidth / charSize).toFixed(0);
  var strToWrite = charToWrite.repeat(numCharsToWrite);
  $('#charSize').text(strToWrite);
  charSize = $('#charSize').width();
  while (charSize < innWidth) {
    strToWrite = strToWrite + charToWrite;
    $('#charSize').text(strToWrite);
    charSize = $('#charSize').width();
  }
  if (charSize > innWidth) {
    strToWrite = strToWrite.slice(0,-1);
  }
  $('#charSize').remove();
  textObj.text(textObj.text() + '\n' + strToWrite);
}
$(function () {
  writeMaxNumCharsInOneLine($('#text'), 'Y')
  writeMaxNumCharsInOneLine($('#text'), 'a')
  writeMaxNumCharsInOneLine($('#text'), 'b')
  writeMaxNumCharsInOneLine($('#text'), 'c')
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<div id="text" style="border: double;width: 50%;height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thats very good - thank you @gaemaf - so I don't have to use a monospaced font.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```js
var char = 'i';
$('#text').html($('#text').html() + char)
var initialheight = $('#text').height();

while ($('#text').height() === initialheight) $('#text').html($('#text').html() + char)
$('#text').html($('#text').html().slice(0,-1))
```

```css
#text {
    word-break: break-all;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

The way this works is that the script inserts a character int the div and gets the height. Then in repeatedly adds characters until the height changes, which indicates that more than one line has occurred. Then it trims the last character that caused it to overflow onto two lines. It's independent of any font characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
$(function() {
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();
   var oneCharacterWidth = $("#text").width();
   var total = windowWidth / oneCharacterWidth;      
   $("#text").html("");      
   for (i = 0; i < total; i++) { 
    $("#text").append("c");
  }
})
```

```css
#text {
  display:inline;
  font-size:12px;
  }

body {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">c</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.   `$("#text").width();` was really helpful - and also very easy. Don't know why I didn't found out. Thank you!

Comment: @NiZa Do you know why there is allways a space on the right side?

Comment: @MaxMara Why did you select this as the accepted if it doesn't work for anyone and leaves a gap on the side?

Comment: @j08691 For me it was the right aproach. But you're right. My fault.

Comment: @j08691 Maybe it's more interesting to find out why that is, and not why he is accepting this answer.

Comment: @MaxMara, I forgot to give the 'c' a `font-size`. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you may want to add more information as well as what you have tried, your question doesn't show much troubleshooting on your side; however I think the code below should work or help you figure out something for what you are trying to do.

```
var w = $(document).width();
var d = $("#text").width();
var s = "";

do{
    s+= "X";
  $("#text").text(s)
  d = $("#text").width();
}
while(d < w)

<div>
<span id="text"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: OK Thank you - next time I try to be more specific and write more text. It's not easy for me, because my english is very bad. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        var b=$( "<span padding=0 margin=0></span>").appendTo( $("#text") );
        do {
           $(b).append("M");
        } while ($(b).width() < $(b).parent().width() )
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="text"></div>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```